# Javascript- What is the difference between the thread pool and web API for handling asynchronous behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, webapi

### Motive

For Javascript and node.js, I am trying to understand the difference between the thread pool and Web API.

### What I Currently Understand

- Thread pool: a multi-thread platform, where each thread executes their own operation.
- Web API: an API built in to the browser. It is part of the event loop, along with the call stack and callback queue to enable asynchronous operations in Javascript.

### What I Am Confused about

It seems like both the thread pool, and Web API, enable Javascript to handle asynchronous behavior.

When Javascript is executing code off the singly-threaded call stack, is it sent to the Web API, which *uses* a thread pool to create a single thread for each asynchronous operation?

If not, how does the Web API and thread pool work together to give Javascript asynchronous capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

**A Few Things First**

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "Web API".  There is no such thing called that built-into nodejs.  There are many, many different libraries in nodejs each with their own API (timers, networking, http requests, crypto, disk I/O, etc...).

If, what you mean is TCP networking or the http networking, then I can explain a few things.

First off, nodejs uses a cross platform library called libuv and that is responsible for most of the interface between the nodejs environment and native code calls to the operation system.  This includes things like file I/O, timers, disk I/O, networking and so on.

The event loop that drives much of nodejs is in libuv.

Secondly, the thread pool is a pool of native threads that are used for certain blocking operations that nodejs wants to be able to present an asynchronous interface to Javascript.  If the interface went directly from Javascript to the blocking native code implementation, then the operation would be blocking and would block the event loop.  So, to make the interface asynchronous, it is moved to a thread.  Examples of native code operations that run in the thread pool are disk I/O and some time consuming crypto operations.

Then, networking is accomplished by using non-blocking operating system APIs so it does not need to use native threads or the thread pool.

**Your Specific Questions**

> It seems like both the thread pool, and Web API, enable Javascript to handle asynchronous behavior.

The design of the interfaces to native operating system things (like networking, file I/O, etc...) combined with the event loop is what enables asynchronous behavior.

> When Javascript is executing code off the singly-threaded call stack, is it sent to the Web API, which uses a thread pool to create a single thread for each asynchronous operation?

Again, it's not clear what you mean by the term "Web API".  There is no such thing that nodejs sends things to in order to execute things asynchronously.

> If not, how does the Web API and thread pool work together to give Javascript asynchronous capabilities?

Converting your "Web API" term to "nodejs API", let's examine how one such operation works.

Let's look as `fs.open()`, a function to open a file.  When you call `fs.open()`, it goes to a Javascript library built into nodejs.  It checks the arguments, handles any immediate errors if the arguments are wrong and eventually calls a binding function that packages the arguments from Javascript into something that native code can handle and then calls a native code function.  These arguments include a reference to the callback that was passed into `fs.open()`.

That native code function gets the arguments into a form that C/C++ can use, gets a thread from the thread pool and then starts running in that thread an OS  call to open the desired file.  The native C/C++, then immediately returns back to the Javascript portion of `fs.open()` which then returns back to your Javascript and your Javascript continues to run any successive lines of Javascript code until it eventually returns control back to the event loop.

Meanwhile the file open operation is running in another OS thread.  When it completes, it inserts an event into the appropriate event queue (a part of the event loop) and returns the thread it was using back to the thread pool.  This event that is inserted into the event queue includes a reference to the callback function that was originally passed into `fs.open()` and any data associated with a result from `fs.open()` (which would include either an error or the file handle).

Sometime later when control goes back to the event loop, it will see that the event queue for file I/O has a pending event and it will grab that event out of the event queue and call the completion callback associated with the event and pass it the data associated with the event.  At that point, your Javascript callback will run and you will get the result of the `fs.open()` call in that callback.

That's an asynchronous operation in nodejs.  Now, keep in mind that not every asynchronous operation uses the thread pool.  Timers, for example do not use threads.  In fact, they don't even use OS-level timers as the event loop has its own timer implementation.  Networking does not use the thread pool either.

Comment: I appreciate your thought out response but in my case, the Web API is an API built into the browser and I’m still having a hard time differentiating the Web API and thread pool. Here’s an example of the Web API enabling async behavior: https://towardsdev.com/event-loop-in-javascript-672c07618dc9?gi=ae00da04cbbd

Comment: @Brendan - You tagged your question with `nodejs` and make no mention at all of a browser in your question.  Please clarify your question (actually edit the question) and ask about a specific API call, not a general question.  If you have code, show the code.  Theoretical questions are way, way harder to get answers for than specific questions that show an actual code example.  In fact, if you had shown a code example here, it would have been clear what you meant by webAPI.  Also, where are you getting information that there even is a thread pool in the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure why your responses have been saying there's no mention of a browser or API. I have quite clearly stated I am referring to the browser's built-in Web API. I even included a link to what I am referring to. My question pertains to the overall Web API that's built into the browser, not any specific API call. My question is definitely a theoretical question, as I am trying to understand foundational information- not a specific call.

Comment: @Brendan - Well, your question starts out with ***For Javascript and node.js*** and that's what I've answered for.  There is documentation on a thread pool for nodejs.  I'm not aware of any specific documentation for "browsers-in-general" since the existence of a thread pool or not is an implementation detail that is not part of any Javascript or webAPI spec.  If you wanted to know how a specific browser works, you would have to look into the architecture for a specific browser implementation.  nodejs is a specific implementation so I've answered for that.

Comment: @Brendan - The term webAPI is a very general and undefined term which I think makes it hard for people to know what you're really asking here.  Both browsers and the nodejs environment have a huge range of APIs that include everything from networking related APIs to crypto APIs and a wide range in between.  I was suggesting you be more specific to increase your chances of getting an answer that is what you're looking for.